# What character to use to put an item at the end of an alphabetic list?

Tags: windows, linux, filesystems, alphabetical-sort

I often prepend '_____' to the item I want in first position.
Is there some sort of magical character I could use to put an item at the end of the list?

Something more **elegant** than "z_item".

Example of this issue for a list of files in Windows Explorer :
[image]

#### Another example from Outlook 2010

Actual folder structure :

- _custom folder1
- _custom folder2
- Inbox
- Sent box
- Spam folder

Expected folder structure :

- Inbox
- Sent box
- Spam folder
- [?]custom folder1
- [?]custom folder2

What caracter could I use?

Comment: THey are lexically sorted based on whatever character set you're using.

Comment: @Brain Roach -- that's what I thought too, except it's more confusing. `chcp` says my default code page  is [CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), and the chart on Wikipedia shows that tilde should sort *after* the letters--but it doesn't. Similarly, other common Windows code pages like [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and [65001 (UTF-8)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) also have tilde afterwards...

Comment: Chinese character "一" for "one" sorts to the bottom of my list and is I think the most elegant character possible

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I found this thread while wanting folders that sort after Z in Finder on Mac OSX. After several false paths and trial and error, here's what I found:

Characters that sort after Z in Finder (in sort-order)

- z   Lower case Z
- ι   Greek letter
- Ι   Greek letter, capital version of above character, not an "I")
- Ω   Omega
- 一  Japanese Character? (Thanks, Jam)
- 口  Japanese character? (Thanks, Jam)
- 末  Japanese character "End" (Thanks, Jam)
-    (a private use character) (Thanks, Peter O.)

These are characters others here and in other places on the web, mentioned sort after Z, but that I found DO NOT sort at the end, at least when sorting by name in Finder on Mac:

† ∆ ~ - ſ [ ø ￭ |

Comment: Thanks, these do seem to be the best suggestions for Win7 File Explorer, I'd be curious to hear which do or don't work in Unix /Linux /Apple-i OS. 
I think probably the thanks in parenthesis should be to the authors rather than the editors.

Comment: I enjoy Ω because it signifies "the end."

Comment: Omega is quite nice, and I like it. But I'm also quite a fan of the "Cyrillic Letter Ha With Stroke" Here's the Capital:  Ӿ  \u04fe and Small:  ӿ  \u04ff versions which both sort after 'z'.  There's also something interesting nearby at \u058d and \u058e :  ֍ and ֎ which, if you look close, are similar but opposite.  Unfortunately, these sort BEFORE alpha chars (in windows explorer.exe), but interesting anyway.

Comment: ~ (tilde) works on Linux.

I love the Omega, lol, but tilde is so much easier to input.

Comment: Another benefit of Ω on the Mac is that it's super easy to type: just press Option + Z.

Comment: They're Chinese Characters.

Answer (score 46):

The Special lead-in Character that will put your folder at the end of the list without having to resort to using the "z" combo: U+E83A: Private Use. In fact, I believe any of the Private Use characters will work. () Just copy and paste the character between the brackets.

Comment: Where can I find a list of these "Private Use" characters? or am I stuck with  ?

Comment: So I created a folder with this at the beginning of the name on my Sharepoint drive and now it's there and I can't access it or delete it.  :|

Comment: If the "Private Use" >  < character renders ugly or does not suit your sense of style, a cleaner option might be the Greek letter "Iota" > Ι < as it's a very simple character that looks exactly like a capital "i"/lowercase "L" and the Greek alphabet sorts after the Latin alphabet on almost all OS's.

Comment: This solution works only in particular situations, while the question seems to ask for a universal solutions. There is already a comment that mentions that such a character cannot be used on Sharepoint successfully.

Answer (score 25):

## Don't mess up things using strange characters!

I would not suggest using ***Private Use characters*** or non-printable characters because they can really mess up things when you access your folder from terminal or programming languages. I had annoying issues using 末 or other special characters.
For example, using **Python 2.7**, this is how you will see your folders with Ω, 末, 口 and non-printable character .

```
os.listdir(os.getcwd())
Out[2]: ['\xe6\x9c\xab ', '\xe5\x8f\xa3 ', '\xce\xa9 ', '\xee\xa0\xba ']
```

For someone or something using your folder structure, accessing the folder would be very confusing (and you can see it from the comments like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086375/what-character-to-use-to-put-an-item-at-the-end-of-an-alphabetic-list/37193588#comment63608859_9492832) to the top answer).

> So I created a folder with this at the beginning of the name on my
> Sharepoint drive and now it's there and I can't access it or delete
> it. :| – Rather Notsay Jun 28 '16 at 21:05

Of course, you can print them, but why make the things so unnecessarily complex?
If you want to stay on the safe side, I would suggest using standard characters. Which is the last one depends on your **File manager**.
So here is some code that creates a bunch of folders with all the printables strings in Python so you can test your file manager.

```
import os
import string
for i in string.printable:
      try:
            os.mkdir(i)
      except OSError:
            print('OSError for %s' %(I))
```

Once you have sorted by name you can get your answer.

### For Windows 10 - Explorer

using standard characters after `z` up to my knowledge there is only `zz` and so on.
[image]

So using  `zzNameOfTheFolder` is an easy and safe way to do to that. So even if it's not nice I would recommend it.

### For Mac OS X El Capitan - Finder

[image]

The z is the last character but note that there is no distinction between capital letters so a folder named `zz` can't be stored in the same directory of a folder `ZZ`

### For Ubuntu 16.04 - Nautilus

[image]

The hashtag `#` is the last character. But if you want some more compatibility with other file managers I would use `ZZ`.

### Something more elegant than "z_item"?

I guess this depends on your own concept of elegance and I think StackOverflow should diffuse best and safest practices, not the most elegant. However, in many cases, symmetry can help. What about these safe perhaps more elegant solutions:

```
ZZFoldernameZZ
Zz-Folder name-zZ
zZ-Folder name-Zz
zZFolderNameZz
zzFoldernamezz
```

Comment: I had pity on your informative answer's negative score and upvoted, but I'd guess the motivation for the downvote is that someone asked a question about how to do something, and do it more elegantly, and you said it shouldn't be done, and gave the same sort of inelegant answer they started with in the question.

Comment: @JaredThirsk I understand but so this would be more a question for superuser. In stackoverflow I think safer practices should be preferred to more elegant practices

Comment: @JaredThirsk G M doesn't tell the OP "don't do it". He says "don't do it the crazy way others suggest". I came here looking for such a char too. But I meant something like `{`, `}` or `~` which are behind z in ASCII. After reading the most up-voted answers, I was tempted to use the Japanese character because it looks kind of cool. Fortunately this answer has put me back on Earth and I'll go on using the good old zzzFileName.

Comment: No, "Ω, 末, 口…" are not non-printable characters, silly.  Upgrade to Python3 already.  ;)

Comment: @GringoSuave what?

Comment: One thing to note is what you consider to be 'standard' characters. In Japan they might think that 一 is totally standard. (Totally agree about non-printing characters, though; that's just asking for trouble.)

Answer (score 11):

Despite being years later I wanted to contribute as none of the previously provided answers worked for me. For reference I'm running win7 ultimate SP1.

The solution I landed on resulted from noticing that any files I made for use with Japanese speaking contacts ended at the end of the file list. Apparently Japanese characters don't count as non-alphanumeric similar to hashmark, hyphen, underscore (which place files at the beginning of the list), but also come after English characters.

For my own use I ended up using the 末 character, which roughly means "end" so it makes sense to Japanese readers and is still different enough from English to not become confusing.

Alternatively I would use 口 or 一 for something more stylistically apparent. It's also worth noting that the shorthand "maru" character ○ does not work and sorts along with other non-alphabet characters at the head of the list.

Comment: 末 is a great idea, has the same meaning in Chinese too: http://hskhsk.pythonanywhere.com/cidian?q=%E6%9C%AB

一 is perhaps a bit confusing as it means 1.

Answer (score 10):

I've found two characters that will put your folders at the bottom of the list.  The first is "ι" and its variant "Ι".  Also, the two best characters to put your folders at the front of the pack are either the No-break space " " and the bullet "·"

For the novice user (like me) who might have found this question and these answers by accident, here's a simple explanation of how to type these characters.  The first is literally a space created by holding the "Alt" key & typing "0160" on your number pad and the second is the "Alt & 250" combination  (Note: A 10-key number pad is best.  If you don't have one on your keyboard, see if you can figure out how to use the alternate number keypad.  This is almost always different than the 1-0 keys at the top of your keyboard.  Look for tiny numbers printed on the edges of your keyboard -usually the "M" "J" L" "I" "O" "P" & 7-0 keys). Or, of course, you can copy and paste the characters in the quotations above (not as easy if you frequently use them as I do).

Here's a short list of special characters to both prioritize your folders or have them appear at the end of a folder list as well as some other folder-friendly characters.  Enjoy (~Peter II)

Useful Characters for Windows Explorer

0160            No-Break Space

·    249/0183    Middle Dot

·    250/8729       Bullet operator

◦    9702           White bullet

›    0155/8250   (See Above)

∕    8275            Division slash

ι                       (End Character)

Ι                      (End Character)

✓  2713?        Check Mark

׃    Last but not least, this alt key (1475) is Hebrew Punctuation Sof Pasuq -This is a great character to use when you can be used in place of a colon)

Comment: I personally chose to use a char in this answer, i.e. · as it's most elegant, so to speak.

Answer (score 8):

no one mentioned `ٴ`. This is an Arabic character and sorts below `z`. Because it's very small, it doesn't annoy.

Comment: Doesn't introduce problems as Arabic is RTL?

Comment: This answer works well for labels in gmail.

Answer (score 6):

Most answers here suggest a non-standard character, which will sooner or later cause issues with various systems.

One answer here, which in my opinion is the best, out of all existing to the moment, is to use the last standard character available on your system. For most of us, that's just `z`. This solution is already suggested by the question and it is indeed not very elegant.

My elegant solution is to use a thesaurus to come up with alternative folder names that sort accordingly. Want your `Archives` folder to be last, rather than first, maybe `Museum` will do it, or perhaps `Smithsonian`, otherwise `Zipped` works for sure.

Of course, this solution involves a bit of extra work, but it is elegant, it expands your vocabulary, and it might bring you a bit of joy in your work.

Comment: it is common courtesy on stackoverflow to comment when you downvote an answer, so please do so.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use a right to left character, for example an Aramaic letter, so that the sorting character appears at the end rather than the front. For example, I've chosen Zayin https://graphemica.com/

So, typing in:

Alpha

is rendered by the text engine as:

Alpha

With the word now sorted below a folder named 'z'.

The full unicode details are:

```
IMPERIAL ARAMAIC LETTER ZAYIN
Unicode: U+10846, UTF-8: F0 90 A1 86
```

Note: I've tested this on MacOS, not every text renderer correctly handles right to left languages.

Answer (score 1):

Using cp1252 and unless you're using the letters ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ alot,  ÷ seems to be an option...

Edit: Using unicode, ￭ (\uffed) might also be a possibility, unless you are writing a lot in Linear-B...

Comment: Or if you limit yourself to 7-bit ASCII, you can't go much wrong with `~`.

Comment: ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ are not really elegant. ÷, ￭ and ~ didn't work.

Comment: Windows file system (order a folder by name for example) + outlook.

Comment: Non-letters are apparently sorted before letters.

Comment: @Neil, `~` isn't greater than `Z` under the MS Access 2010 database engine with an English or Romanian locale, it's even less than `a`.

Answer (score 1):

For web and SQL purposes, pre-pending CHAR(127) forces text to the bottom and adds no visible character. Works at least for our use of SQL and the jQuery datatables plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like memorizing special alt codes that you don't regularly use in day-to-day typing just remember these three rules:

1. The exclamation point `!` is the first character on a US keyboard
2. `UPPERCASE` letters come before `lowercase` letters
3. The tilde `~` character is the last character on a US keyboard

You can easily navigate these rules in any terminal, but you may need to type `\!` or `\~` (depending on your shell).

Example Listing (e.g. `tree -aL 1`):

```
.
├── !first
├── .hidden
├── UPPER
├── lower
└── ~last
```

And if you don't like those characters, for whatever reason, here they all are in sorted order:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Comment: Annoyingly ~ sorts above A in Finder on the Mac (but works as expected on the command line).

Answer (score -1):

Those that find that most of the codes given here produce different characters than what is described, you probably have  *EnableHexNumpad*    enabled in  *HKCU \ Control Panel \ Input Method*... this is by and large a  *good*  thing, but you do have to convert the codes to hex and precede them with '+' sign (on the num keypad), eg. for the colon at Alt+1475, use the hex equivalent of Alt+5C3 ( hit  ***Alt***   with the left hand and hold it down, then with the right hand hit the keypad  ***+***  … then  ***5***  , ***C***  , and  ***3***  … then let go of  ***Alt***   ).

And, speaking of colons, there's another (smaller) good colon at Alt+1361 hex, which would be Alt+4961 without HexNumpad *if*  it works that way.