# Minimum letter for string sorting

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Question:
**I have Strings: `"A", "C", "D", "1", "И" (Russian), "你" (Chinese)`. And I have string `let alwaysFirstString = "?"`
I want `alwaysFirstString` to be always first when I use general iOS sorting. What should be the `alwaysFirstString` instead of "?" ?**

*Why I need that*:

In my application I display contacts like in **Telegram** application:

- At first I need to display contacts that have their own contacts in my application (server returns me these contacts)
- After that I display other contacts (grouped by the first letter in their surname)

I display contacts in group `UITableView`. So in my `DBContact` object in core data I have sectionInfo field. Usually this field = A, B, C, F (The first letter of surname), but for some contacts (I want them to be always first) I need to have other symbol. So this symbol should always be the first when I use regular `sortDesctriptors` in `FetchResultController` (better for all languages).

**Here is the code:**

```
let entityName = kDBContact
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<DBContact>(entityName: entityName)
//            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext)
//            fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
// sort
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "sectionInfo", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "nameAndSurname", ascending: true)]
// sometimes we have predicate when user tries to search smth
var predicate: NSPredicate?
var formatForPredicate = ""
// filter not to show fake contacts
formatForPredicate += "(isFakeContact == false)"
var argumentArray = [AnyObject]()
// text filter in search bar
if help_needToShowFilteredContacts() {
    if formatForPredicate.length > 0 {
       formatForPredicate += " AND "
    }
    formatForPredicate += "((nameAndSurname CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (phoneNumbers.numberOnlyDigits CONTAINS[cd] %@))"
    argumentArray.append(resultSearchController.searchBar.text! as AnyObject)
    argumentArray.append(resultSearchController.searchBar.text! as AnyObject)
}
sectionNameKeyPath = "sectionInfo"
// filter to show only favourites
if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == segmented_favouriteIndex {
    sectionNameKeyPath = nil

    if formatForPredicate.length > 0 {
       formatForPredicate += " AND "
    }
    formatForPredicate += "(isFavourite == true)"
}
if formatForPredicate.length > 0 {
   predicate = NSPredicate(format: formatForPredicate, argumentArray: argumentArray)
}
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>, managedObjectContext: DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath, cacheName: nil)
```

So you can see `fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "sectionInfo", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "nameAndSurname", ascending: true)]` . So in sectionInfo I have this First characters of the surname, and I want registered contacts (with special character in sectionInfo) to be always the 1st.

Comment: Most people have no idea what the Telegram is or how it displays contacts. Please update your question so it fully explains your need without reference some other app.

Comment: And what is your question? You posted some information but you didn't actually ask anything or explain any problem you are having. Update your question with an actual question or issue. Show relevant code. Explain what problem you have with it.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: You can use any character you want. Is that all you want to know?

Comment: I can't use any character, because it will not be true for all possible string arrays. For example if I use alwaysFirstString = "1", it will be the 1st string for this array, but will be not first string if I insert Russian "а". But may be there is a special character like "!" (just for example) that always be the first

Comment: It can be any character you want. But until you update your question with relevant code showing your issue when trying to use a specific character, no one can show you how to fix your code so it works like you want it to.

Comment: The question is not about code, the question is about minimum symbold when you sort strings and I think I explained it properly

Comment: You are missing the point. You can use any character you want. Sort order is irrelevant because you can put your special character and its section at the top. But since you refuse to post relevant code, no one can show you how to update your code appropriately.

Comment: @rmaddy , I updated the text with the code. Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "" for maximum symbol and " " for minimum. Later in fetched result controller delegate I have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections {
            let currentSection = sections[section]
            let name = currentSection.name
            if "" == name {
                return "#"
            }
            else if " " == name {
                return "Registered contacts"
            }
            return name
        }

        return nil
    }
```

I found last symbol here [What character to use to put an item at the end of an alphabetic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086375/what-character-to-use-to-put-an-item-at-the-end-of-an-alphabetic-list)